# Maximizing speed of a loop/apply function

Tags: r, performance, loops, apply

I am quite struggling with a huge data set at the moment. 
What I would like to do is not very complicated, but the matter is that it is just too slow. In the first step, I need to check whether a website is active or not. For this intention, I used the following code (here with a sample of three API-pathes)

```
library(httr)

Updated <- function(x){http_error(GET(x))}  
websites <- data.frame(c("https://api.crunchbase.com/v3.1/organizations/designpitara","www.twitter.com","www.sportschau.de"))
abc <- apply(websites,1,Updated)
```

I already noticed that a for loop is pretty much faster than the apply function. However, the full code (which has around 1MIllion APIs to check) still would take around 55 hours to be executed. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe `unlist(lapply(websites[,1], Updated))` is faster?

Comment: Based on this code, my guess is that the vast majority of your time is spent inside one function call; I'm guessing `apply`'s overhead has nothing to do with it. (BTW, I would probably have done `lapply(vec_of_urls, Updated)` instead of `apply`.)

Comment: using abc <- lapply(websites,Updated) I got this error: Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE (unfortunately I could not find out why until now).

Comment: Use `websites[,1]` instead of `websites`

Comment: lapply(websites[,1], Updated) worked, but is still too slow. For the first 150 URL paths, unlist(lapply(websites[,1], Updated)) takes 1.249 seconds, and apply(websites,1,Updated) 1.271 seconds

Comment: And how long does it take using a `for` loop?

Comment: 1.650 mins (Seems that I was wrong that the for loop was faster, I am sorry). BTW. the others fo not run 1.249 and 1.271 secs but minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, something like this would work for passing multiple libraries to the PSOCK cluster:

```r
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
     library(data.table)
     library(survival)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! :)

Answer (score 1):

The primary limiting factor will probably be the time taken to query the website. Currently, you're waiting for each query to return a result before executing the next one. The best way to speed up the workflow would be to execute batches of queries in parallel.

If you're using a Unix system you could try the following:

```r
### Packages ###
library(parallel)

### On your example ###
abc <- unlist(mclapply(websites[[1]], Updated, mc.cores = 3))

### On a larger number of sites ###
abc <- unlist(mclapply(websites[[1]], Updated, mc.cores = detectCores())

### You can even go beyond your machine's core count ###
abc <- unlist(mclapply(websites[[1]], Updated, mc.cores = 40))
```

However, the precise number of threads at which you saturate your processor/internet connection is kind of dependent upon your machine and your connection.

Alternatively, if you're stuck on Windows:

```r
### For a larger number of sites ###
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = "PSOCK")
clusterExport(cl, varlist = "websites")
clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, library(httr))
abc <- parSapply(cl = cl, X = websites[[1]], FUN = Updated, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
stopCluster(cl)
```

In the case of PSOCK clusters, I'm not sure whether there are any benefits to be had from exceeding your machine's core count, although I'm not a Windows person, and I welcome any correction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: For now, I am stuck on Windows... I tried your code and I really like the approach! After changing "websites[[1]]" to "websites", it ran substantially faster than my original code! That was really helpful (Time difference of 19.73397 secs for 150 URLs)

Comment: No worries. I used websites[[1]] because you had your initial input vector stored in a data frame. Using this syntax would extract the first element/column from the data table. Other people used websites[, 1], which would also work. There's also a parApply() function in the parallel package if you want to mirror the approach of your initial query.

Comment: One additional question: How could I load several packages if I want the function to be more complex?E.G. instead of only loading httr also load data.table or whatever?

Comment: I believe you can run a clusterEvalQ() function for each library you want to add to the function. If the function is something you're created yourself then you would need to add the function's name to the varlist vector in clusterExport(). This is the main bummer with the parallelisation method required by Windows... it's more complicated. You need to manually export everything to the cluster that it needs.